# Directive scope variables are undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written the following directive:

```
WeatherApp.directive('map', function () {

    return{
        restrict : 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            var latitude = scope.lat;
            var longitude = scope.lon;
         var  mapOptions = {
             zoom: 8,
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude)
         };

         console.log("latitude ="+latitude);
         console.log("longitude ="+longitude);
         map = new google.maps.Map(elem[0], mapOptions);
        }
    }

});
```

I am using this directive in my html as follows:

```
<div class="google-map" map=""></div>
```

There is a controller HomeCtrl which is parent of this directive. HomeCtrl uses WetherService to fetch the lat, lon and sets it to the scope variable, but in the directive the value of latitude  and longitude is undefined. I think this is because directive is getting compiled before the controller executes and fetches weather data.  How can I set the scope data inside the directive? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the directive:

```
<div class="google-map" map lat="lat" lon="lon"></div>
```

And the directive declaration should contain `scope`;

WeatherApp.directive('map', function () {

```
return{
    scope: {
        lat: '@', // or '='
        lon: '@', // or '='
    },
    restrict : 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        var latitude = scope.lat;
        var longitude = scope.lon;
     var  mapOptions = {
         zoom: 8,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude)
     };

     console.log("latitude ="+latitude);
     console.log("longitude ="+longitude);
     map = new google.maps.Map(elem[0], mapOptions);
    }
}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create a watch over the lat and long value and create the map only when they get assigned.

In your scope create a object location that gets assigned the value returned from service. `$watch` for this variable change in your directive code.

```
 link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
         scope.$watch("location", function(newValue,oldValue) {   
            if(newValue) {
              var  mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(newValue.lat, newValue.long)
              };
              map = new google.maps.Map(elem[0], mapOptions);
            }
        }
  }
```

The data returned from the service needs to be assigned to scope variable `location`. You extend this sample to use isolated scope, but still you would have to do a watch.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is move the weather data retrieval to a service. Inject the service in your directive and set the `lat` and `lon` scope variables in a callback or after the promise of your data is fulfilled (depending on how you implemented the data retrieval).

Comment: Weather data retrieval is already in a service. This service is invoked by the controller which sets the scope data.

Comment: Why don't you keep the data in the service? In this way you can access them from anywhere, be it your controller or your directive. It's much simpler, and is also the purpose of a service.

Comment: Thanks, I will try what you said.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `lat` and `lon` on `$watch`.